# robots.txt encoding issue

Tags: 7

I'm in charge of a website for my company, which runs Drupal 7.66 (PHP 5.3.3), for a few years now. Since a few months, I discovered a strange behavior regarding the robots.txt file. In some case, the encoding is totally messed up.

Here is a brief description of the problem:

- If I am connected to the website: no problem, the robots.txt file is well displayed in the browser
- If I am NOT connected to the website (like all our users and the search engine robots): it randomly appears broken, and I identify that as an encoding issue. By “randomly”, I mean that sometimes when I check the robots.txt while not being connected, its ok, but sometimes it's broken. I can't find a pattern that will allow to reproduce the error.

The robots.txt is managed through admin/config/search/robotstxt thanks to the module RobotsTxt version 7.x-1.2

Here is a screenshot to illustrate the issue (I had to hide some parts of the images):

[image: Encoding issues]

Of course, the webmarketing team noticed me that Google can't crawl the robots.txt file because of that issue:

[image]

I made quite a lot of searchs on drupal.org, Stackoverflow, Google... but couldn't find anything related.
I am not a developer, but I work with a guy which is specialized in Drupal and he can not figure it out either.

Any idea? Of course if you need any further information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Some comments: 1) Reading your statement "The robots.txt is managed through admin/config/search/robotstxt", I assume you are using the RobotsTxt module. You should state this clearly in your post and include which version of the module. Including which specific version of Drupal and PHP is also nice. 2) Have you searched the module issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/robotstxt There seems to be several related (closed) issues. 3) I see that you have posted the same question in the drupal.org forums. Please keep this two questions (with answers) in sync ...

Comment: Thank your @hansfn for your comments. 1) I just checked and indeed the website is using the RobotsTxt module, v. 7.x-1.2. I wasn't aware of that (I didn't set up the website) and will update my question. 2) Thanks for the link to the module issue queue, I'll check that link and keep that question updated if I find something. 3) Sure, I will keep the two questions synchronized, it may help someone else.

Comment: Ok, thanks to you @hansfn, I found this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt/issues/2352295 and it seems to be very related to my question. I'll contact the developer I'm working with and the team that is managing the server (big company with lot of representatives/procedures) and I will update the question both here and on drupal.org as soon as I have more information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Thanks to @hansfn comment, I found a similar issue on drupal.org: [Doesn't work for anonymous users](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt/issues/2352295)

I told about it to the developer I work with and he updated the RobotsTxt module from the version 7.x-1.2 to the version 7.x-1.4, and it solved the problem.